# Message State of Oracle Advanced Queue not updating after Dequeue using ODP.net

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, advanced-queuing, odp.net-unmanaged

I am  trying to Dequeue a Message from oracle AQ using ODP.NET by  service

Once the Service Dequeue the message  , that record should not be available for other instances of services ,means it should be locked till transaction is committed or transaction expires

My problem is I am able to successfully dequeue the records but the message state is not updated from ready state to any other states, I am able to get the payload data also

```
 Public Shared Sub DequeueMessage(ByVal MessageID As String)
        Dim constr As String = "mystring"
        Dim con As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(constr)
        Dim queue As OracleAQQueue = New OracleAQQueue("MyQueuname", con)

        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim oracleCommand As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand("Select MSGID  from INTEGRATION_MSG_QUEUE where msgid='B85439241C9241A4A6B1869F08F382E7'", con)
            Dim K = oracleCommand.ExecuteScalar()
            Dim rawBytesFromOracle As Byte() = TryCast(K, Byte())
            Dim txn As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleTransaction = con.BeginTransaction()
            queue.DequeueOptions.Visibility = OracleAQVisibilityMode.OnCommit
            queue.DequeueOptions.Wait = 0
            queue.DequeueOptions.DequeueMode = OracleAQDequeueMode.Locked
            queue.DequeueOptions.MessageId = rawBytesFromOracle
            queue.MessageType = OracleAQMessageType.Udt
            queue.UdtTypeName = "TRIGGER_AUDIT_TYPE"
            Dim deqMsg As OracleAQMessage = queue.Dequeue()
            Dim data As TRIGGER_AUDIT_TYPE = CType(deqMsg.Payload, TRIGGER_AUDIT_TYPE)
            Console.WriteLine("Dequeued message...." & data.CMESSAGEBODY) ''Iam getting data here
            txn.Commit()
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

My Queue is like

```
BEGIN DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE(
     Queue_table        => '"instance"."INTEGRATION_MSG_QUEUE"',
     Queue_payload_type => '"instance"."TRIGGER_AUDIT_TYPE"',
     Sort_list          => 'ENQ_TIME',
     Compatible         => '10.0.0',
     primary_instance   => 3,
     secondary_instance => 2);
  END;
  
   BEGIN DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE(
     Queue_name          => '"instance"."INTEGRATION_MSG_QUEUE_Q"',
     Queue_table         => '"instance"."INTEGRATION_MSG_QUEUE"',
     Queue_type          =>  0,
     Max_retries         =>  5,
     Retry_delay         =>  0,
     dependency_tracking =>  FALSE);
  END;
```

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need dequeue it with:

```
queue.DequeueOptions.DequeueMode = OracleAQDequeueMode.Remove
```

or:

```
queue.DequeueOptions.DequeueMode = OracleAQDequeueMode.RemoveNoData
```

When you are using `Locked` mode, you are just browsing and obtaining a lock to the message. You need to actually update it.

See:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleAQDequeueModeEnumeration.htm#ODPNT3687